# A difficult question about diffeomorphism about submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ and $N$ be two smooth manifolds, and $f: M \to  N$ be a submersion , ${{f}^{-1}}(y)$ is compact for all $y$ in $N$. Then prove for any $x$ in $N$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that ${{f}^{-1}}(U)$ is diffeomorphic to $U\times {{f}^{-1}}(x)$.
I've thought this problem for a long time, but I don't know to use which method. Cobordism can help to solve this question?

Comment: I don't see how cobordism would help.  I would try using the implicit function theorem instead.

Comment: show that $f$ is proper and look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann%27s_fibration_theorem

Comment: You are missing some hypothesis to conclude that $f$ is proper. For example, without any additional hypothesis, we have a counterexample $M=(0,2)$, $N=S^1$ (the unit circle in the complex plane), and $f(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$.

Answer (score 12):

As Blah said in the comments, if we can show that $f$ is proper (and in fact [it is!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7096/proper-maps-and-families-of-compact-complex-manifolds)), your statement is just Ehresmann fibration theorem.

To give a proof of Ehresmann fibration theorem, we will use [theorem of tubular neighborhoods](http://www.scribd.com/doc/65943441/32/Tubular-Neighborhood-Theorem). This result says that a neighborhood $W$ of $M_y := f^{-1}(y)$ in $M$ is diffeomorphic to a neighborhood of $M_y$ in its normal bundle, and in particular that there exists a differentiable retraction $r : W \to M_y$. But then , consider the map 
$$(r,f):W \to M_y \times N.$$
This map has a differential (which is invertible along $M_y$). As $M_y$ is compact, there exists an open set $W' \subset W$ containing $M_y$ such that $(r,f)_{|W'}$ is an embedding. Finally, as $f$ is proper, $W'$ contains an open set $W''$ of the form $f^{-1}(U)$, where $U \subset N$ is a neighborhood of $y$. Then clearly $(r,f)(W'') = M_y \times U$ and we have shown that $(r,f)$ is a diffeomorphism from $f^{-1}(U)$ to $M_y \times U$.

Comment: @ Jacob:Thanks!But I'll make a completment.I've seen somewhere that ${{f}^{-1}}(x)\ and\ {{f}^{-1}}(y)$ is also diffeomorphism.This is a stronger conclusion.How can we get this?

Comment: This is the link:[link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47373/if-f-m-to-n-is-a-smooth-map-between-compact-connected-manifolds-and-operat)

Comment: I've just responded you here.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47373/if-f-m-to-n-is-a-smooth-map-between-compact-connected-manifolds-and-operat

Comment: @ Jacob: Thank you!I've understood.But where have you learnt these beautiful theorem like Ehresmann fibration theorem?Can you recommended me some modern books about differetial topology?I've read some books which are a little basic that they don't involve some advanced topics.

Comment: Dear Henry:
I read this theorem on Claire Voisin's book "Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry" chapter $9$, when dealing with family of complex manifolds. By the way, it would be nice if you accept the answer that you consider helpful ;)